# How can I extract paragraphs of approx. 500 words ending with full stop from big string in python?

Tags: python, string, paragraph

sample paragraph : Anthony Edward "Tony" Stark was born on Friday, May 29, 1970, in Manhattan, New York City, to Howard and Maria Stark. Stark had become good friends with Edwin Jarvis, the butler of the Stark family, who watched over him throughout all of his childhood.[3] Stark's early life was often dominated by the absence of his father, who he would later describe as both 'cold' and 'calculating'. Growing up, Stark had issues with Howard, who never told his son that he loved, or even liked him. Since Stark was so young, Howard could not tell his son his plans for him.[4] Howard constantly talked about his admiration for Captain America, which caused Stark to develop hatred and resentment towards the super soldier.[7] However, Stark had a loving relationship with his mother, who was more gentle and nurturing; he enjoyed hearing Maria play the piano.

Comment: Please point out in your question how the above text should be captured.